# How Can I Clone Color Picker From Google?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, color-picker

This [site](http://www.materialdoc.com/color-picker/) tells me in order to use this color picker I need to clone them - the project repo. But I don't have git. Can I still use them? I never experienced using git nor background about it.

[image: colorPick]

If I can use this - which of this should I use? I accept recommendation My min API 19 - target API 25.

[image: list]

EDIT: 
Step 1: 
I paste the git command. And go to - new -> import module.

[image: git]

Step 2: Stuck with this solved by - (I cut out the folder of the clone project paste it outside) And import new module

[image: module]

I tried to sync the project but error

```
dependencies {  
compile project(':colorpicker')}
```

PROBLEM :

[image: error]

Comment: but you have android studio, dont you?

Comment: Yes, I have. version 2.2.2

Comment: so your problem is solved, use it

Comment: i cloned the project and kept it in zippy share for you, use this link to download project http://www62.zippyshare.com/v/UuD3H4HG/file.html

Comment: Git is needed to clone/download project after that you just need to import that project as dependency inside android studio

Comment: I'm almost done, I don't know that Android Studio have built in git. I thought I need to install them separately. The problem now is to locate the clone file - path. I updated the question.

Comment: It should be in `D:\AndroidProjects\Animated\colorpicker`

Comment: @Redman - I got an error for the color picker, due to buildToolVersion. Do you have any idea? I opened the colorpicker and look for the gradle but didn't find version there.